# Webpack Compile: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env' when deploy production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, webpacker, react-rails

i use capistrano to deploy my rails project( Rails 6.0.0, Ruby 2.6.0)

i get bellow log when start `bundle exec cap production deploy

> ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
>
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>
> Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env'

and

> ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js
>
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
>
> Error: Cannot find module '@babel/preset-env'

But when i test in local `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile` . It built successful

my **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my_app_name",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^4.0.2",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "core-js": "2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.0",
    "trix": "^1.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.6",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.3.1"
  }
}
```

my **app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
// Support component names relative to this directory:
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

my **app/javascript/packs/server_rendering.js**

```
// By default, this pack is loaded for server-side rendering.
// It must expose react_ujs as `ReactRailsUJS` and prepare a require context.
var componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
var ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

any solution? Thank You

Answer (score 7):

Anything you want available when compiling in production mode needs to be in `dependencies`. Move `@babel/preset-env` out of `devDependencies` into `dependencies` in package.json. You can also delete `babel-preset-env` since that is redundant.